# How to setup webdiver to perform actions in background?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, thucydides

I am currently working in Automation QA. Our project using Java: jbehave, thucydides, selenium. We are working in Ubuntu OS.

Every time I run my tests, I have to stop doing everything(coding, browsing the web), because every click or any action of selenium is taking driver window(we are using chrome driver) in focus(makes window active) and if i do something i mess up the test. Our team is wasting a lot of time because of this.

We have tried Phantomjs, it doesn't work correctly, cannot find elements etc... And also to run tests in virtual machine using vagrant isn't working for us(for company specific reasons).

It is fine if Chrome driver will take over active window when it starts, as long as it would continue performing different actions in background. Strange, but in my previous project(windows, c#, mstest) chromedriver would behave exactly like this without any additional setup.
Please help, I know few other teams having this issue. Seems like this issue only on Mac and linux.

Comment: Can you get a dedicated machine(s) that runs your tests? I am pretty sure that I never had to have Chrome in focus when I run my tests.

Comment: I have to debug test locally. Instead of criticizing and -1 my question just help. Try to do it using my setup.

Comment: I don't understand your comments: "I have to stop doing everything" and "I have to debug test locally". Your question suggest that you are doing _something_ wrong, are unhappy about it, and you want us to fix it with no specific information of what it is you are actually doing. This is a site to help with programming (code) problems, hence the -1.

Comment: Why would i ask this question if i had dedicated machine? Just think about it! That's your problem if you cannot understand my questions because they are clear. You never had perform debug on your tests? First of all this platform is made to ask question when you are doing something wrong. Secondly, before posting here, i have talked to many teams in my company and even in different countries. They all have this problem if they are using mac or ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having this issue for a long time I have finally found a good solution. This issue still remains on ChromeDriver level, so if there are any updates on this side let me know.

The easiest way to run tests in Ubuntu in a background is using VNC Server. Here are the steps you should follow:

1. Install vnc server from ubuntu terminal:

   **sudo apt-get install vnc4server**
2. Start server with any number(I use 7). First time doing it enter password for vnc server(**Remember it!**).

   **vncserver :7**
3. To start server in full screen add "geometry" to last command with your screen resolution for example:

   **vncserver :7 -geometry 1920x1080**
4. Download some VNC Viewer. I use Real VNC.
5. Go to Real vnc viewer, start new connection and enter:

   VNC Server: **localhost:7**

   Encryption: **Let VNC Server choose**
6. Press connect and enter your vnc server password(the one from step 2).
7. New window should be opened, open new terminal in it.
8. Run your test from terminal. I use java maven project so for me it works like this. Navigate to project folder and run: **mvn clean install**

If you want simply to run test in hidden mode using only terminal(without opening vncviewer) use this command:

**cd path/to/project**

**xterm -display localhost:7 -e mvn clean install**

If you want to stop server:
 **vncserver -kill :7**

Hope this will help many of you.

Answer (score 0):

For me (I had the same problem in my Grails project's functional test using Chrome; not with Firefox) works this set up:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--start-maximized --disable-popup-blocking");    
new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Regards

Comment: What? Explain please!

Comment: Reverted vandalism. If you want to delete, click "delete" below your post.